# Creating a round (clipping) mask to unveil a ray of lights

Tags: javascript, css, masking, clip

Imagine having a set of light rays surrounding a circle - just like the sun. What I want to do is reveil the rays, so the appear to be "rising" from the sun.

In Flash I would be able to create a nice effect for this by doing something like the following steps:
- Divide the rays into x amount of groups (symbols)
- Create a circle mask that will scale up "grow" to reveil the rays
- Run the circle mask with 0.3 delay on each of the x amount of groups

I figured that I could emulate something similar with the CSS clip property, but that only works with rectangles?

Any suggestions on how this could be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

A rectangle (square) with border-radius (exceeding 1/2 of its width) perhaps?

Comment: As far as I understanding the clipping property is CSS based and can only be defined as hiding/revealing in rectangular form? So setting the border-radius on the element to something circular wouldn't do anything - but a good suggestion none the less